# Hybris Backoffice update with ant updatesystem

Tags: spring, ant, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-web

I want to update backoffice with ant updatesystem, I'm doing it this way:

```
ant updatesystem -DconfigFile=configWithBackofficeExt.json
```

For example - I have "Administration" and "MyWidget" widgets, I want to remove "Product Cockpit", so I remove config from *extension-backoffice-widgets.xml.
And now, If I run my ant command - dropdownlist with widgets not updated.
If I run an update from HAC or in backoffice with F4, all works fine.

As far as I understand, there is no web-context when I running ant command, so there are no beans responsible for update/rebuild of widgets.xml(composed widget config, which we can see in orchestrator).

Is there any way to attach backoffice web context, so that beans would be available when ant command called. Or maybe there is a more elegant way to do it?

Ps: I know about config properties to update backoffice on startup/login, but still prefer to do it with ant.

Comment: The aim of ant updatesystem is to update the database according to new models. If you want to update backoffice on startup just use the configs. "there is no web-context when I running ant command, so there are no beans responsible for update/rebuild of widgets.xml" -> yes and it should not be done by ant but when the server starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after research, I haven't find appropriate way to update backoffice with *ant updatesystem*.

To update backoffice upon application start or/and login to backoffice we can use these properties:

```
backoffice.cockpitng.reset.triggers=start,login
backoffice.cockpitng.reset.scope=widgets,cockpitConfig
```

When the application starts, configuration files will be reassembled and saved. This won't take much time(I didn't notice any impact on application startup time, with all OOTB backoffice extensions enabled, sometimes app took 10 sec longer to start, sometimes 10 sec faster).